# Flying from KL, Malaysia to Lucknow, India with layover in Singapore

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, layovers, singapore, malaysia

I am an Indian passport holder travelling from KL, Malaysia to Lucknow, India via Singapore.  I have a multiple entry Singaporean visa and eNTRI from Thailand. My first flight (Jetstar) (KUL - SIN) arrives at 12:50. The outbound flight from Singapore to Lucknow is on the same day but from a different airline (Scoot). I have no check-in luggage and my outbound flight from (SIN - LKO) is at 16:00.

Will I have sufficient time to change the flights?
Do I need to go through the immigration twice(for both inbound and outbound flights) in Singapore?

This is not a duplicate since I am asking about the Singapore airport in general and not only about the minimum connecting time. My question is about staying at the airside and taking the outbound flight(different PNR) without going through immigration.

Answer (score -3):

You go through immigration when you're entering the country, and you're only entering Singapore once. But you'll have to go through security after you've checked in for the second flight.

Comment: Why would they need to enter Singapore if they have no luggage to collect?  Also, SIN does not separate incoming and outgoing passengers, security is at the gate.